# Not able to Create file usind PHP?

Tags: php, permission-denied

So what I'm doing is creating a directory with a name from the file , then creating a text file in it.

My directory structure is like this where I am trying to create the file:

> /users/username/www/practise

and the code is:

> $path = /home/username/www/practise/
>
> $counter_file = "/home/username/www/practise/counter.txt";
>
> if (file_exists($counter_file))  {
>
> **line 2**    :   if(!($fp = fopen($counter_file, "r")))
>
> die("can't open the file");
>
> ```
>           $counter = (int) fread($fp, 20);
>           fclose($fp);
>
>           $counter = $counter + 1 ;
>       $path .= $counter
>
>           mkdir($path , 0777);
>           $path .= content.txt;
>
>           if (!($fp = fopen($path, "w"))) 
>           {
>               die("cannot open the file");
>
>           }
>           fwrite($fp, "{$content}");
>   // content is the variable that has value equal to "file is created"
>           fclose($fp);
>
>           if(!($fp = fopen($counter_file, "w")))
>               die("cann't open the file");
>
>           fwrite($fp, $counter);
>           fclose($fp);            // and store the counter value in the file
>
>           if(!($fp = fopen("$counter_file", "w")))
>               die("cann't open the file");
>
>           fwrite($fp, $counter);
>           fclose($fp);
> ```
>
> }

**The error which I am getting is:**

> **Warning: fopen(counter.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied on line 2**
>
> **can't open the file**

Comment: Try `/practise/counter.txt`.

Comment: still the same error @putvande

Comment: do you have write permissions?

Comment: What permissions are on the `practise` directory

Comment: the permissions on the practise directory is 777

Comment: what OS? normally `/home/username` folder is not accessible for others. If that is not the case, try checking if `SeLinux` is blocking access. Try to set `SeLinux` to `Permissive` and check (if using SeLinux). Never use `777` unless it is necessary why do you need execute permission for a file to read it?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that code is producing that result? There's no "can't open the file" string in the code you pasted. Somehow I think we are missing something.

Comment: the die statement just below the line 2 @juanrpozo

Comment: Says "cann't" not "can't". Which line is line 1? Where is $counter_file defined? Apparently it is defined as "/home/username/www/practise/counter.txt" but the Warning message says only "counter.txt".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have permission on the directory but not on your file. Use chmod(777) on your txt file. 
Keep in mind, it's not the best to set 777.

Comment: I don't understand your request. Instead of 777 for only read the file ?

Comment: is there a way that to open the file in write mode with 777 permission ?

Comment: I don't guess. You must use the chmod() function to set the permissions.